# can't migrate from visual studio to linux with c++ and opengl

Tags: c++, linux, visual-studio, opengl

I'm having classes of computer graphics on OpenGL. There we study and work with Visual Studio 2015 while I run Linux on my laptop. So there some differences between composing a program in our classes and in lessons I found on Wikibooks. I tried to run one tutorial code from there and everything was fine, while I couldn't run my code I wrote at my lesson.

So I tried manipulating with my and tutorial code. I succeeded a few. The program runs but not shows my figures. So it actually must show a chesstable. But, for my regret, it shows a background color only. What may be wrong with that?

The first part on `onDisplay()` is not displayed. The commented part is from tutorial which works and shows a triangle.

Full code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
/* Use glew.h instead of gl.h to get all the GL prototypes declared */
#include <GL/glew.h>
/* Using the GLUT library for the base windowing setup */
#include <GL/freeglut.h>

GLuint program;
GLint attribute_coord2d;

int init_resources()
{
    GLint compile_ok = GL_FALSE, link_ok = GL_FALSE;

    GLuint vs = glCreateShader( GL_VERTEX_SHADER );
    const char *vs_source =
    #ifdef GL_ES_VERSION_2_0
        "#version 100\n"  // OpenGL ES 2.0
    #else
        "#version 120\n"  // OpenGL 2.1
    #endif
        "attribute vec2 coord2d;                  "
        "void main(void) {                        "
        "  gl_Position = vec4(coord2d, 0.0, 1.0); "
        "}";
    glShaderSource( vs, 1, &vs_source, NULL );
    glCompileShader( vs );
    glGetShaderiv( vs, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &compile_ok );
    if( !compile_ok )
    {
        fprintf( stderr, "Error in vertex shader\n" );
        return 0;
    }

    GLuint fs = glCreateShader( GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER );
    const char *fs_source =
    #ifdef GL_ES_VERSION_2_0
        "#version 100\n"  // OpenGL ES 2.0
    #else
        "#version 120\n"  // OpenGL 2.1
    #endif
        "void main(void) {        "
        "  gl_FragColor[0] = 0.0; "
        "  gl_FragColor[1] = 0.0; "
        "  gl_FragColor[2] = 1.0; "
        "}";
    glShaderSource( fs, 1, &fs_source, NULL );
    glCompileShader( fs );
    glGetShaderiv( fs, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &compile_ok );
    if( !compile_ok )
    {
        fprintf( stderr, "Error in fragment shader\n" );
        return 0;
    }

    program = glCreateProgram();
    glAttachShader( program, vs );
    glAttachShader( program, fs );
    glLinkProgram( program );
    glGetProgramiv( program, GL_LINK_STATUS, &link_ok );
    if( !link_ok )
    {
        fprintf( stderr, "glLinkProgram:" );
        return 0;
    }

    const char* attribute_name = "coord2d";
    attribute_coord2d = glGetAttribLocation( program, attribute_name );
    if( attribute_coord2d == -1 )
    {
        fprintf( stderr, "Could not bind attribute %s\n", attribute_name );
        return 0;
    }

    return 1;
}

void chess( double x, double y, double w, double h, int k )
{
    glColor3f( 0.6, 0.6, 0.6 );
    glRecti( 20, 20, 480, 480 );

    for( int i = 0; i < 8; i++ )
    {
        glRasterPos2i( ( i + 1 )*x + 20, 30 );
        glutBitmapCharacter( GLUT_BITMAP_9_BY_15, 'A' + i );
    }

    for( int j = 0; j < 8; j++ )
    {
        for( int i = 0; i < 8; i++ )
        {
            if( k % 2 == 0 )
            {
                glColor3f( 1, 1, 1 );
            }
            else glColor3f( 0, 0, 0 );
            glRecti( x + w*i, y + h*j, 2 * x + w*i, 2 * y + h*j );
            k++;
        }
        k++;
    }
}

void onDisplay()
{
    glClearColor( 0.5, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0 );
    glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT );

    glUseProgram( program );
    glEnableVertexAttribArray( attribute_coord2d );
    double x, y, w, h;
    int k;
    x = 50;
    y = 50;
    h = 50;
    w = 50;
    k = 1;
    chess( x, y, w, h, k );
    glFlush();
    /*
    GLfloat triangle_vertices[] = {
    0.0,  0.8,
    -0.8, -0.8,
    0.8, -0.8,
    };
    // Describe our vertices array to OpenGL (it can't guess its format automatically)
    glVertexAttribPointer(
    attribute_coord2d, // attribute
    2,                 // number of elements per vertex, here (x,y)
    GL_FLOAT,          // the type of each element
    GL_FALSE,          // take our values as-is
    0,                 // no extra data between each position
    triangle_vertices  // pointer to the C array
    );

    // Push each element in buffer_vertices to the vertex shader

    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
    */
    glDisableVertexAttribArray( attribute_coord2d );
    glutSwapBuffers();
}

void free_resources()
{
    glDeleteProgram( program );
}


int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
    glutInit( &argc, argv );
    glutInitContextVersion( 2, 0 );
    glutInitDisplayMode( GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_DEPTH );
    glutInitWindowSize( 640, 640 );
    glutCreateWindow( "chesstable" );

    GLenum glew_status = glewInit();
    if( glew_status != GLEW_OK )
    {
        fprintf( stderr, "Error: %s\n", glewGetErrorString( glew_status ) );
        return 1;
    }

    if( init_resources() )
    {
        glutDisplayFunc( onDisplay );
        glutMainLoop();
    }

    free_resources();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Could you please nartow your code down to a [mcve] for the question? Currently there's a lot of stuff in there that's not relevant to your problem.

Comment: @Rabbid76 works fine! thanks a lot. I thought of it but didn't know how to fix it.